# Command to check the content of a file as a conditional statement

Tags: bash, shell

I am looking for a command which will check content of a file and the if the content is found I will not write it again, if its not found then the same will be written.

For example:

```
cat sample1.txt
test1 1.0.0.0
test2 1.0.0.0
test1 2.0.0.0
```

Out of these three entries, I want only the first unique entries to be written into the output file. My output file should be

```
cat sample_op.txt
test1 1.0.0.0
test2 1.0.0.0
```

My question here is, without using a loop can I get some command to perform this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk it is simple:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++' file

test1 1.0.0.0
test2 1.0.0.0
```

This awk command uses an associative array `seen` with the key as `$1`. FOr each row it will check if `$1` is available in `seen`. If yes then line is printed otherwise value of `$1` entry is incremented by `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this worked.. Thanks again :)